# WPF open a file automatically using file binarydata from database

Tags: c#, wpf, file, mvvm

In WPF Application using MVVM model

What I want : In one viewmodel, when a button was clicked, a binary file data will be read from my database, and then this file should be automatically opened by corresponding application.

What I did: read the file binary data and save it in the computer, then using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(this.SavePath)` to open it.

`(this.SavePath)` stands for downloading file save path. Because this `Process.Start()` method can open file using the file path.

It works good. But I don't want to download it. Don't want to save it in the computer.  I want to use its binary data to complete this directly.

Yours answer will be appreciated!

Comment: Well, since `System.Diagnostics.Process` only acceps files, you wont be able to achieve your goal. Also every Application i know, will not accept a MemoryStream or equal as Parameter. Why should they?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I hope Microsoft can provide more convinent more direct operation to resource